# The bot does not send a message to the dm

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make that when a user join to the server where this bot is located, the bot should send him a greeting message in the dm. But when connecting, the bot does not send a message. No errors are displayed. How can I fix this? My code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join():
    await member.send("Welcome!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@client.eevent
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("Welcome!")
```

you need to have an arguement in the function!

Also you need to enable intents in your bot

```py
client = discord.Client(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all(),case_insensitive=True)
```

you also need to enable all intents in the discord Developer portal

Comment: If the event doesn't fire at all he also needs member intents

Comment: yeah I forgot about those

Comment: Also if a bot joins it would likely cause an error since you can't dm bots. This probably doesn't need to be added but just in case it's asked, you could either use a `try-except` statement or check if the member's a bot via `member.bot`